# How to show validation errors in array format

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

This is how i define an arras of objects to send data from vue js to laravel through api

```
productdetails: [ 
        { 
        userid:'1',
      productlimit:'',
      categoryid:'',
      product_desc:'',
      productprice:'',
      productname: '',
      productimage:null,

    }
      ],
```

The validation i have defined that i am sending data in the form of array to laravel and validation looks like this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'productdetails.*.image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,png',
        'productdetails.*.product_name'=>'required|string|unique:products',
        'productdetails.*.categoryid'=>'required',
        'productdetails.*.productlimit'=>'required|max:100'
       
     ]);
```

The validation error message i defined looks like this:

```
 if ($validator->fails()) {    
        return response()->json(['messages'=>$validator->messages(), 'status' => 400]);
    }
```

The response of validations errors messages look like this

```
{
"messages": {
    "productdetails.0.image": [
        "The productdetails.0.image field is required."
    ],
    "productdetails.1.image": [
        "The productdetails.1.image field is required."
    ],
    "productdetails.2.image": [
        "The productdetails.2.image field is required."
    ],
    "productdetails.0.product_name": [
        "The productdetails.0.product_name field is required."
    ],
    "productdetails.1.product_name": [
        "The productdetails.1.product_name field is required."
    ],
    "productdetails.2.product_name": [
        "The productdetails.2.product_name field is required."
    ],
    "productdetails.0.categoryid": [
        "The productdetails.0.categoryid field is required."
    ],
    "productdetails.1.categoryid": [
        "The productdetails.1.categoryid field is required."
    ],
    "productdetails.2.categoryid": [
        "The productdetails.2.categoryid field is required."
    ],
    "productdetails.0.productlimit": [
        "The productdetails.0.productlimit field is required."
    ],
    "productdetails.1.productlimit": [
        "The productdetails.1.productlimit field is required."
    ],
    "productdetails.2.productlimit": [
        "The productdetails.2.productlimit field is required."
    ]
},
"status": 400
```

}

This seems fine but I need validation error messages like this

```
  {
"messages": {
"0": [
    "The productdetails.0.image field is required.",
    "The productdetails.1.image field is required.",
    "The productdetails.2.image field is required."

],

"1": [
    "The productdetails.0.product_name field is required.",
    "The productdetails.1.product_name field is required.",
    "The productdetails.2.product_name field is required."
],
"2": [
    "The productdetails.0.categoryid field is required."   
    "The productdetails.1.categoryid field is required."
    "The productdetails.2.categoryid field is required."
],
"3": [
    "The productdetails.0.productlimit field is required.",  
    "The productdetails.1.productlimit field is required.",   
    "The productdetails.2.productlimit field is required."


  ]
},
"status": 400
}
```

How can i do that?????

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Before you continue, I am asking you to reconsider reasons of your intention because there is high chance you will need to change more default code in the future. My advice is to keep default code and just adapt frontend to read it. Can you describe issue that you have with current code (error response) use?

Comment: I don't have an error but what I have to do is to send the following error response to the front end and I am having trouble doing it. What I did is to get all errors messages in an array using  ***validation->message()->all()*** and then i applied loop and wanted to push new data in the loop but that does not seem to work.